# Why parallelized code will not write in an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, parallel-processing, f#, excel-interop

Writing many worksheets in an `Excel` spreadsheet can take a while. Parallelizing it would be helpful.

This code works well, it makes an `Excel` spreadsheet pop on the screen with four worksheets named `Sheet1`,`1`, `2`, and `3`.

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
open FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq

let backtestWorksheets = [1..3]

let app = new ApplicationClass(Visible = true) 

let workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)

let writeInfoSheet (worksheet: Worksheet) : unit =

    let foo i =
        let si = string i
        worksheet.Range("A" + si, "A" + si).Value2 <- "Hello " + si
    List.iter foo [1..10]

let wfm = [1, writeInfoSheet; 2, writeInfoSheet; 3, writeInfoSheet]
          |> Map.ofList

let adder (workbook : Workbook)
          (i        : int)
                    : unit =

    let sheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add() :?> Worksheet
    sheet.Name <- string i
    wfm.[i] sheet

List.iter (adder workbook) backtestWorksheets
//PSeq.iter (adder workbook) backtestWorksheets

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

However, replacing the line starting with `List.iter` with the commented line just below it makes a spreadsheet with the same four worksheets pop up, but all worksheets are blank.

So my question is: Why can't code parallelized with PSeq write to Excel?

Remark:

Originally I had a different problem. Maybe because in my application the worksheets are heavier when I try to run code similar to the above with `PSeq` there is an exception that says

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$Fractal13>.$Program' threw an exception. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))
```

This does not happen with `List.iter` replacing `PSeq.iter`.

I was not able to replicate this exception in a simple enough context to be a proper SO question, but I would still be interested in any suggestions for dealing with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could write separate worksheets at the simultaneously and combine them afterwards?  Even if there's a way to get it working into the same file at the same time, I wouldn't recommend it.  (As for "why" it's not supported, that's a broad question you'd have to ask Microsoft.)

Comment: I know nothing about F#, so I don't know how you would implement this, but the solution to the "The message filter indicated that the application is busy" is to implement your own message filter.  see: [How to: Fix 'Application is Busy' and 'Call was Rejected By Callee' Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228772.aspx).  Pay attention to the requirement of running the filter is a STA thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` code was never designed to be called from multiple threads at once. [Here's a question someone asked](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f0a6dfd1-74a0-4ac0-b806-28dccbe5442b/can-i-update-an-excel-workbook-from-multiple-threads?forum=exceldev) in the MS Office forums about doing an update in multiple threads (in C#). I'll quote the relevant parts of that answer here:

> Using multi-threading to search in multiple worksheets ends up with using the heart of Excel – the Excel.Application object, which means threads need to be queued to run one-at a time, depriving you of the desired performance improvement for the application.
>
> [...]
>
> All of this is because the Office object model isn't thread safe.

It looks like you're stuck with using a non-parallel design if you're calling anything in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespace.

**Edit:** [Aaron M. Eshbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1748071/aaron-m-eshbach) had a great suggestion in the comments: do all the background work on multiple threads, and use a `MailboxProcessor` to do the actual updates to the spreadsheet. The MailboxProcessor's message queue will automatically serialize the update operations for you, with no extra work required on your part.

Comment: You could do all the background work on multiple threads and use a `MailboxProcessor` to serialize the actual updates to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I am not sure the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` cannot be used with parallelized code. The workbook had about 20 worksheets and only three of those generate exceptions when created from `PSeq.iter`. They are the only ones that have charts with many thousands of data points. So the code thar creates them has to be sequential (`List.iter`). The other ones are called with `PSeq.iter`. There is a time saving of about ten seconds (40s -> 30s) from doing so (I tested switching from `List.iter` to `PSeq.iter` on the group that can be paralleleized several times, the time savings were consistent).

Comment: @Soldalma - "Not thread safe" does not mean that running that code from multiple threads at the same time will always fail, it just means it isn't guaranteed to always succeed. The fact that it's working fine for you so far on the shorter worksheets doesn't mean it will *always* continue to work. You might run into a situation where heavy CPU or I/O load elsewhere makes your shorter-worksheet threads fail where they normally succeeded, because the timing of the threads changed in a way you can't predict or control. Safer to serialize everything, IMHO.

Comment: @rmunn - Thanks. I managed to reduce the time from 40 seconds to 7 seconds, and since I run this many times every dayit is a significant difference. I am the only user of this code so I will keep it like this until problems arise, then fix them by serializing the culprit worksheets.

Comment: @rmunn  - `Aaron M. Eshbach's` suggestion is a good idea but it looks like most of time was spent on the actual updates to the spreadsheet, which would remain serialized anyway.